# Pagination with Handlebars/Backbone

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, pagination

I want to implement a simple pagination using Handlebars. I am using bootstrap 3. This is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class = "categories-block">
 {{#each category}}
  <div class = "category">
  <div class = "item">
    <h2>{{itemname}}</h2>
    <a href = "#" class = "link">View Category</a>
    <p class = "item-desc">{{itemndesc}}</p>
  </div>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
</div>

<div class="pagination">
   <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</div>
```

**MODEL**

```
var categorymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: "http://localhost/category.json",
  defaults: {

  }
});
```

Right now, everything I get from my model is displayed there. How can I paginate, display 5 items in one page.
Thanks in advance

Comment: And what you did yourself? Where is cycle for draw page links?